How can I allow only one nav menu to be open at a time?
I have a navbar created using React-Bootstrap. It consists of both a main menu (always collapsed) and a dropdown menu.
If I click on the dropdown menu it opens. If I toggle the main menu while the dropdown menu is open, it first closes the dropdown menu before opening the main menu. This is the behavior I would expect.
However, the opposite is not true. If I first toggle and open the main menu, then with the main menu open I click on the dropdown menu, the main menu doesn't close before opening the dropdown menu, it opens over the top off the main menu.
So the question is, how can I get the main menu to close before opening the dropdown menu so that only one navbar menu can be open at any given time?
Here is the component:
import { Container, Dropdown, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavTest() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar expand={false} bg="primary">
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Acme Co.</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Dropdown>
                        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="button-outline">
                            Dropdown Menu
                        </Dropdown.Toggle>
                        <Dropdown.Menu>
                            <Dropdown.Item href="#">Dropdown Link 1</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item href="#">Dropdown Link 2</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item href="#">Dropdown Link 3</Dropdown.Item>
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="me-auto">
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="#" eventKey={1}>Main Menu Link 1</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="#" eventKey={2}>Main Menu Link 2</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="#" eventKey={3}>Main Menu Link 3</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    )
}

